# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwings'

Tags: python-3.x, excel, automation, windows-10, xlwings

I'm trying to run the python script which has Xlwings for preparing excel in Windows 10 but I get the following error when I tried to run the script. I have already installed the Xlwings libraries.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Python automation\PT.py", line 17, in <module>
    import xlwings as xw
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwings'
```

Can anyone please advise what's wrong with the xlwings. Please help

Comment: Have you installed xlwings in your virtualenv?

Comment: @Luffli, Might be No. How can I do that ..??

Comment: Its in the docs https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/installation.html. And you can research on virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

On your project folder, from your terminal, try doing this:

```
python -m venv venv
Windows - venv/Scripts/activate
Unix - source venv/Scripts/activate
```

You'll create a virtual environment. Then just `pip install xlwings` + other dependencies & re-run your project. Hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).